# EventLog File Enable Hourly Logging

Tags: eventlogfile

we’re interested in ingesting the EventlogFile on an hourly basis.In the below link,3rd bullet point, 2nd para, it says “If both hourly and daily logs are enabled…” where in the Salesforce instance can you enable hourly monitoring of EventlogFile object?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/event_log_file_hourly_overview.htm

Answer (score 0):

You would query hourly event log files in the same way you query 24-hour log files. As per https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/event_log_file_hourly_query.htm

> 1. In Workbench, select utilities | REST Explorer.
> 2. Replace the existing text with:/services/data/v API_version .0/query?q=SELECT+Id+,+EventType+,+Interval+,+LogDate+,+LogFile+
> 3. Append the following to the query to make it complete: FROM+EventLogFile+WHERE+EventType+=+'URI',+Interval+=+'Hourly'
> 4. In the query, Interval=Hourly makes sure that only hourly event log file data is returned. Alternatively, you can use Sequence to
>    filter out 24-hour event log files (Sequence!=0). To get both hourly
>    and 24-hour files, use Sequence>=0.
> 5. Click Execute.

Incase you are unable to query this information despite having needed licenses, you can log a case with Salesforce support to verify if the perm "Hourly event log files" is enabled in your salesforce org.